# Wordpress crontrol - server max_execution_time time issue

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am using Wordpress crontrol plugin for running a long script. this script is running for a long time (20 - 30 minutes) after every couple of hours.

But it stops after every 2 - 3 minutes.

I cant setup cron job for this due to wordpress dedicated hosting & no cPanel access.

I tried setting up set_time_limit to 0, phpinfo is reflecting this but no change in response.

Please help.

Comment: What do the server PHP error logs say when it stops unexpectedly?

Comment: only few warnings, no fatal error. I am sure warnings can't stop the script   @MattGibson

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes`

Place this at the top of your PHP script, or use `.htaccess` file

`<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 300
</IfModule>`

If it didn't help, than you need find way to access your php.ini file, or some other way for configurating php.

Comment: thanks for help buddy. i tried the same options before, but after discussion with Hosting team, I found that in shared hosting i am not able to increase to limits. for this VPS hosting is required .